# Uninstall MySQL and perform first time setup

Tags: server, mysql, minecraft

I know this seems like a repeated question but I've tried every other answer and none of them worked.

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://bukkit.org/threads/guide-full-guide-for-creating-a-mysql-database-for-use-with-plugins-on-ubuntu-debian.11443/) in order to create a database for my Minecraft server but before that, I've tried with a YouTube video on how to install MySQL.

I don't know what I did but I messed up. MySQL has a password I do not know, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling with various tutorials as I told before but none of them worked, the moment I reinstall MySQL it still asks for my password, data is still saved somewhere somehow.

Even if I manage to get in, I can't do the `mysqladmin -u root -p create minecraft` command that's on the guide, it would just get my in an arrow promp loop like this "->" no matter what I type it just drops another one, I've also searched help for that but no luck, I just found I can go back with \c but as long as I try again or any other thing I end up there again. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide is totally wrong. The command `mysqladmin -u root -p create minecraft` must be run from your shell, not when you are connected to the command-line client.

From the client, you can create the database using

```
CREATE DATABASE minecraft;
```